# Getting from Tajikistan to China

Tags: china, borders, tajikistan

I hear that pass in Kulma Pass on Tajikistan-China border is closed for foreigners since 2008 (caused by Olympics). 
Is it still closed? Is there any other pass between Tajikistan and China?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no other pass from Tajikistan directly to China which is open to tourists on the [Chinese side of the border](http://caravanistan.com/border-crossings/tajikistan/).  The suggestion is generally to use [Kyrgyzstan](http://caravanistan.com/border-crossings/kyrgyzstan/) for land crossings, however, the border between [Kyrgyzstan to Tajikistan](http://top.rbc.ru/politics/12/01/2014/898857.shtml) is currently closed.

The other possibility is to use [Uzbekistan](http://caravanistan.com/border-crossings/uzbekistan/) as a intermediate point and then travel to Kazakhstan or Kyrgyzstan and then to China, but it will be the long way around.

**Additional Info**

Similar info about the [Qolma crossing](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/thread.jspa?threadID=2335708) from Lonely Planet.

Comment: At least two of the three border crossing between Kyrgyzstan and Tajikistan are usually open. But you should check before going there, they are a long way from everything. I met a cyclist from Hong Kong who crossed the Qolma pass in July 2014, but for now that only seems to work if you have a passport from "greater" China.